# i-tec USB 3.0/USB-C Dual HDMI Docking Station won't find display on 20.04

Tags: 20.04, display

My i-tec USB 3.0/USB-C Dual HDMI Docking Station works fine under Windows11 but won't find the display on Ubunut 20.04.

I used the i-tec ubuntu driver for 20.04 but it simply does not show a display.

If i connect the hdmi directly, it works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

With a little help from the i-tec support i got it to work using their "community driver" instead of their own driver:

- Disconnect the docking station
- Run the following command in the Terminal: `sudo displaylink-installer uninstall`
- Restart the laptop
- Install  the community-modified drivers: https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian
- Restart the laptop
- Connect the docking station